# Ellipsizing an NSMenuItem's title to the width of the menu

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, ellipsis

I want to programatically change an NSMenuItem's title, but ellipsize it so that this modification never causes the menu to increase in width. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this yourself.  NSString has some methods added by AppKit for determining the length of a string, given a certain font, etc.  If you find the string is too long, remove a chunk from the middle, measure again, and keep doing that until the string is short enough.

However, this might be overkill, since `NSMenuItem` will "ellipsize" the title automatically (although this can result in super-wide menus)